# Make a Menu in three.js

Tags: javascript, menu, three.js

A team member in a programming project has written the graphical aspect of our software using three.js (the abstraction of WebGL), and due to imposing time constraints, I've been tasked with coding up a Menu / Display thing for the program.

(The program displays a 3-D graph, and this 'menu' will appear (when triggered) and display information about a particular node, including an image, some text and maybe a scroll-able area of text)

I've had little to no experience with three.js or WebGL and am trying to wrap my head around the whole 'textures' and 'mesh' and 'materials' and what have you; I'm not sure how I'd approach creating such a menu/display.

There's little I can find for making menus in three.js with some (probably naive) Google searching, and I don't have time to really slug through a whole WebGL tutorial.

Can anybody steer me in the right direction?
Is there some convenient three.js extension or module for making displays / menus?
Does anybody know how I should/could implement this using Three.js objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason not to use HTML ?

As you run your app in modern browser environment - I guess - HTML/CSS/Javascript is by far the easiest way to make the interface.

If the menu is only supposed to interact with the scene (changing a size, rotation, light, toggle things, etc), you can even go with [DAT.Gui](https://code.google.com/p/dat-gui/), many Three.js examples use it, and you can find a tutorial here http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/14/dat-gui-simple-ui-for-demos

Comment: The menu must appear in the 3D space that the graph is in; I don't see a way to do that in html. DAT.GUI is for changing variables as far as I can tell, which is not at all what I've specified my menu must do

Comment: Okay, I understand dat.gui is not an option.
Maybe you could use a CSS3DObject, as in http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html ?